# Joomla! Module not showing up after implementing sh404sef

Tags: joomla, joomla-sef-urls, joomla-module

I have placed a module in the position "Below content" on my Joomla!-site. It is supposed to show up below the content (well ...) like shown in the picture attached. Problem is, it only does so when I set it to 'show on all pages', and I only want it to appear on a selected few pages. When I set it to only show on these pages, it disappears!

It is the carousel called "Andre modeller"[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua2Fd.png)

Now, I have disabled the module except on this page (and the other beachflag pages): http://anansi.dk/strandflag-a

And it is gone. It worked before I implemented sh404SEF. Anyone?

:-) Astrid

Comment: It looks like you loose Itemid variable during sh404SEF URL translation. Check in the admin panel if all URLs come with something like &Itemid=XXX where XXX is any integer number greater than 0.

Comment: They do. For instance, this http://anansi.dk/strandflag-a has a non-sef url that looks like this  index.php?option=com_configbox&Itemid=463&cat_id=31&lang=da&prod_id=45&view=category

Comment: Check the word 'category' there is an invisible sign which turns it into 'cate‌%E2%80%8Bgory'. Also the link you've specified is actually rewritten to http://anansi.dk/gadeflag-b
All translated by sh404SEF URLs are unique?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the answer. I thought the point of sh404SEF was to rewrite the URLs and make them friendly. I don't know how the word "category" is effed up like that. Could it be the ConfigBox acting up?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that stumbles across this question, the sh404sef user manual page on [Troubleshooting issues with missing modules](http://anything-digital.com/sh404sef/docs/troubleshooting-issues-with-missing-modules.html) might be of assistance.

In brief, first ensure that the module is set to display on the specific menu. Then:

1. In Joomla's menu list, find the Itemid of the menu item that displays the page. It will be listed in the last column labelled ID. You will need this ID later in the last step.
2. Open the sh404SEF URL manager and locate the SEF url for that page which is not displaying the module. You will notice that the SEF url will have at least 1 duplicate URL for this item. Click on the this number to open the Duplicates Manager.
3. There should be a native URL such as (index.php?option=com_k2&Itemid=345&id=214&lang=en&view=item) that contains the Itemid you found in step 1 above. You need to make it the Main url by clicking on the Make Main button.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does not work - they all look like this:  index.php?option=com_configbox&cat_id=27&lang=da&prod_id=2&view=category